# Database Module with TypeORM throws dependency related exception during application startup

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I am working on a solution with multiple APIs that connects to the same database. I want to reuse the database entities so I decided to create a Database Module that include the entities and a Dynamic Module that configures TypeORM. And I also wanted to share this as a npm package.  For now I am installing the npm package directly from my local disk. I created the following DatabaseModule and this is included in the npm package along with the entities for the database model.

```js
import { DynamicModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule, TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({})
export class DatabaseModule {
  static register(options: TypeOrmModuleOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: DatabaseModule,
      imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
          ...options,
          entities: [__dirname + './models/**/*.model{.ts,.js}'],
        }),
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

Once I install the npm package on my API project, I am importing the new DatabaseModule in my AppModule imports like this.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    DatabaseModule.register({
      type: 'mssql',
      host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
      port: +process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
      username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
      options: {
        trustServerCertificate: Boolean(
          process.env.DATABASE_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATES,
        ),
      },
    }),    
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When I try to run the API app it fails with the following error message.

```
ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TypeOrmCoreModule (TypeOrmModuleOptions, ?). Please make sure that the argument ModuleRef at index [1] is available in the TypeOrmCoreModule context.
```

I'm still trying to figure out the problem, so some guidance to push me towards the right direction would be awesome.

Comment: For me it's a problem with your dependancies. In yours project you have installed TypeORM ? Not in you package but in your project ? 
Because, if typeorm is not in your dependancies of your package is not installed